Importing height map - scale and dimensions
New blender user here. I'm amazed at what this software is capable of.
My main interest is taking real world terrain data.
I did try BlenderGIS, but I had some problems with it.
In addition, I do prefer to be able to make these kind of maps without using add-ons.
I’ve watched and read several tutorials about this, and I’m able to get quite good results, but I struggle understanding units and how I should import the heightmap to blender.
Based on my understanding and playing around with this:

Displace uses height maps, which may be imported as PNG or TIF. I use TIF.
The height map should contain values ranging from 0 to 1. 0 representing lowest value and 1 representing highest value.

I think I get this right.
My question is related to scale and how blender deals with this. 
My test file consists of 7562 rows and 5082 columns. Each cell is $200\times200$ meter, i.e. square pixels. This means that my entire height map spans an area that is $7562\times200=1512.4$ kilometers wide (x-axis) and $5082\times200=1016.4$ kilometers high (y-axis).
In some of the tutorials I've seen, they imported the height map by looking at the number of pixels, dividing by 100 and setting this number as the scaling factor, for X and Y, respectively.
In my case, this gives me an X-scale of $7562\times100=75.62$ and Y-scale of $5082\div100=5082$. This does give a reasonable result, but when I turn on the wireframe, the cells are rectangular, not square (ref. input height map are square pixels; $200\times200$ meter).
So it seems like the aspect ratio is messed up.
